# Howto disable Animations in MUI Autocomplete using sx props

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I like to use the MUI Autocomplete Combobox component (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#combo-box), but with disabled animations, i.e. no transitions when open and close the options and also no background animation when the end adornment triangle icon changes.
Does anyone know how to configure the animations with the sx prop?

Comment: Autocomplete components in MUI have no animations by default. what do you mean by animation exactly?

Comment: You would need to clarify which css property it is that you are trying to overwrite then apply an undefined / new css value to the sx prop, i.e. overwriting the css that mui has set by default. Or something along those lines.